# Why is the operation $e^{\ln x}$ destructive?

Tags: calculus

If I enter these two limits on wolfram alpha I get two different results. If anyone could explain to me why that is so?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[3]{n})}{\ln(1 + \sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[4]{n})} = \frac{3}{2}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{\ln(1+\sqrt{n}+\sqrt[3]{n})}}{e^{\ln(1 + \sqrt[3]{n} + \sqrt[4]{n})}} = \infty$$

To me this seems weird...

Comment: You didn't actually use the $e^{\ln x}$ operation, you just used $e^x$

Comment: Exactly, I don't know what I was thinking! Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simpler example: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n}{2n} = \frac{3}{2}$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{3n}}{e^{2n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^n = \infty$. $\exp$ "magnifies" the discrepancy between two divergent sequences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Makes sense.